# high resolution CSS sprites

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing, css-sprites

I'm generating CSS sprites.  I want to use these sprites at multiple sizes.  I've searched but haven't been able to figure out how to functionally scale a CSS sprite--e.g. if the original sprite is at 150x150 and I want to display it at 50x50, how can I do that?  `background-size` seems to break it.

I can just generate the sprites at the needed sizes, but when I do this via ImageMagick's `-resize` I take a noticeable resolution hit.  Usually, if I find an image is unacceptably low resolution on a webpage, I just make a bigger image and scale its size, functionally increasing the resolution of the image.

Since I can't figure out how to scale a CSS sprite, I'm a bit stuck--how can I achieve arbitrary resolution using a CSS sprite?

Comment: I think this has more to do with ImageMagick's resize quality than CSS.

Comment: @Diodeus It's not fair to blame ImageMagick. Unless you are using vector graphics you're not going to be able to get perfect quality arbitrary resolution scaling from any software.

Comment: Usually you start with a higher resolution, then make lower resolution versions from that. If IM can't do that well, then it's crap.

Comment: If you have a 50x50 image and then resize it to 48x48 something is going to have to give somewhere. What software are you using ?

Comment: I am using ImageMagick, and it seems like `resample` should be able to do what I want, but I haven't been able to figure out how to work it.  Given that I have a large image, getting a smaller, higher resolution one does seem like it should be possible.  But it's not clear to me how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant way you can do this is by using CSS3 `background-size`, but this is not supported on all browsers (e.g. IE<=8).  You might look into IE specific transforms or filters that you can use and then add the `-mz-`, `-webkit-`, and `-o-` selectors to get the effect you want on the browsers you are targeting.

The least elegant way to do this is by faking the sprite scale and positioning.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="ex3">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/g/600/400"/>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.ex3 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;  
}
.ex3 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px; 
    width: 150px;  /* Scaled down from 600px */
    height: 100px;  /* Scaled down from 400px */
}
```

**The Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/s2dfT/

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to change the size of a CSS sprite, sorry.

As for generating the CSS Sprites, try:
http://spriteme.org/

Or for general image editing:
http://www.gimp.org/

You could edit the individual image components, and then use SpriteMe to generate the Sprite. You don't want to generate the sprite and then resize the entire Sprite image, as then your CSS positions for each individual element would be thrown off.

Answer (score 0):

The options I see are:

1. Either have the sprite's contents in different sizes in one sprite.
2. Or take the original sprite and manually resize it one time to create a smaller copy of it. Then reference the smaller sprite version for when you need the smaller images.